# React router dom only re-render a component on page on dynamic routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm currently working on a chat application.

Currently in my `App.tsx`, I have the following.

```
<Route path="/" element={<RootLayout />}>
  <Route index element={<Landing />} />
  <Route path="auth" element={<Auth />} />
  <Route path="chat" element={<Chat />} />
</Route>
```

In my `Chat.tsx`, I have a `Navbar`, `Sidebar`, and `MainPanel` component. How can I modify this so that the chat route takes an id parameter, and depending on the id of the chat, I re-render just the `MainPanel` component to update the chat (since the `MainPanel` component is the one displaying the conversations) rather than re-rendering the entire `Chat` component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `ChatLayout` component which will have all the `Navbar` , `Sidebar` components which you want to reuse and not re-render on change in `chat-id`.
Then create a nested route like

```
<Route path="/" element={<RootLayout />}>
  <Route index element={<Landing />} />
  <Route path="auth" element={<Auth />} />
  <Route path="chat" element={<ChatLayout />}> 
    <Route path=":id" element={<MainPanel />}>
  </Route>
</Route>
```

ChatLayout

```
const ChatLayout = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <Sidebar />
      <Outlet />
    </>
  );
};
```

MainPanel

```
const MainPanel = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  return <h1>MainPanel - chat id - {id}</h1>;
};
```

Inside the `MainPanel` you can use the  `useParams()` hook to get the `id`.
Note you should do all your routing and navigation using either `useNavigate()` hook or the `<Link to="route-to-navigate"> route name</Link>`

For more detailed info regarding the above hooks and `<Outlet/>` you should checkout the react-router documentation of the version you are using. They have decent tutorials and examples to get started.

If you want to checkout the code , I have created a sample sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/awesome-breeze-kcr9lm?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqgvsvq00007356k1j36atws%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70.95969287953454%252C29.040307120465457%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqgvsvq00003356k70uvu9e5%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqgvsvq00004356kew4pn04c%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqgvsvq00006356k0xnui4bk%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clqgvsvq00003356k70uvu9e5%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqgvsvq00002356kqfv8ewtu%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A14%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A27%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A14%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A27%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.js%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqgvsvq00003356k70uvu9e5%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqgvsvq00002356kqfv8ewtu%2522%257D%252C%2522clqgvsvq00006356k0xnui4bk%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqgvsvq00005356klibiwkhq%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252Fchat%252F1%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqgvsvq00006356k0xnui4bk%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqgvsvq00005356klibiwkhq%2522%257D%252C%2522clqgvsvq00004356kew4pn04c%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqgvsvq00004356kew4pn04c%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Answer (score 0):

use [useParams](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-params).

You can get id by using `useParams()`, pass it like
`<Route path="chat/:id" element={<Chat />} />`

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  useParams,
} from "react-router-dom";

const Navbar = () => {
  return <h1>Navbar</h1>;
};

const Sidebar = () => {
  return <h1>Sidebar</h1>;
};

const MainPanel = ({ chatId }) => {
  return <h1>MainPanel - Current Chat ID: {chatId}</h1>;
};

const Chat = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <Sidebar />
      <MainPanel chatId={id} />
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<h1>Home</h1>} />
        <Route path="chat/:id" element={<Chat />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

If you wanna play around with [code](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/infallible-wave-fddf96?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A2%2C9).